# debounce with ignoring all calls except the last using lodash

Tags: javascript, debouncing

If I have a function `foo`. It receives many calls at a short period of time.

```
function foo(name) {
  console.log(`Hi ${name}, it is now: `, new Date());
}
```

Delaying consecutive function invocations (debouncing ) is working fine using lodash .

```
   const debouncedFoo = _.debounce(foo, 1000 );
```

However, my target is to NOT execute this whole fleet of invocations even the timeout (`1000` )  have elapsed, and  consider **only** the **last invocation** to be executed .

In other words, if i called `debouncedFoo` 5 times within 900 ms (which is less than "wait param" 1000ms ), I want `foo` to be executed only once which is the last (5ᵗʰ) call .

Reading lodash documentation , I understood that `debounce` is overloaded by 3ʳᵈ argument which is options. I used them and the expected behavior does not happen:

```
   // first attempt
  const debouncedFoo = _.debounce(foo, 1000, {leading: true} );
  // second attempt
  const debouncedFoo = _.debounce(foo, 1000, {trailing: false} );
```

Comment: Isn't it thottling then that you want? https://lodash.com/docs/#throttle

Comment: It's been a while but for anyone else (like me) stumbling across this - something that can be overlooked sometimes is accidentally recreating the debounced function on every state change.

Comment: Glorious comment @AndyO . This was true in my case - I was using debounce inside a react component. Re-renders were creating multiple instances of debounce. Fixed by moving function out of the component. You saviour ✌️

Answer (score 14):

Like @AndyO mentioned, make sure you're not re-creating the debounced function upon every state change.

I had the same problem, so I used `useCallback` to solve it.

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'React';
import { debounce } from 'lodash';

const myFunction = () => { // some logic };
const debouncedMyFunction = useCallback(debounce(myFunction, 300), []);
```

Edit:

If your are already using `callback` check the dependencies, if dependencies are changing then a new `callback` will get created on every update.
Remove such dependencies and pass them as arguments to your function.

Comment: That was my case

Comment: One can optimize this code snippet by using `useMemo()` instead of `useCallback`: useCallback results in debounce() being invoked on every render, as useCallback will just make sure to return the same ref to the first debounce() call (unless dependencies change). So while useCallback will get you the desired effect (the same function ref to the result of the first debounce() call), It is often better to use useMemo() here, as useMemo will only call debounce() during initial rendering of the component. Example: `const debouncedMyFunction = useMemo( () => debounce(myFunction, 300), []);`

Comment: it should be upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

Not familiar with lodash, but you can implement that behavior easily:

```
function debounce(cb, duration) {
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      cb(...args);
    }, duration);
  };
}
```

```js
function debounce(cb, duration) {
  var timer;
  return function() {
    var args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      cb.apply(null, args);
    }, duration);
  };
}

var call = debounce(console.log.bind(console), 1000);
setTimeout(function(){ call(200); }, 200);
setTimeout(function(){ call(400); }, 400);
setTimeout(function(){ call(600); }, 600);
setTimeout(function(){ call(800); }, 800);
setTimeout(function(){ call(900); }, 900);
```

Comment: Thank you , I already implemented something like this , however, i want to leverage lodash to mitigate unit-tests in the project, then increase coverage.

Comment: OP asked for a solution using lodash, don't see how this is relevant.